# TextView's Text is not updated in UI Thread

Tags: java, android, textview

I've got a problem. I want to change the text of a textview after selecting an item (ringtone). I got the selected ringtone title and wanted to write it on the text attribute of textview, but it doesn't work (I am in the UI Thread not in a seperate thread).

Here's the code, where i want to update the text:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK: 
        String ringtoneTitle = null;
        ringtoneUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if(ringtoneUri != null) {
            ringtoneValue = ringtoneUri.toString(); //diesen Wert später in Datenbank abspeichern !!
            ringtoneTitle = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri).getTitle(this); //Titel getten
        }
        textViewRingtone.append(": " + ringtoneTitle); //Titel zu TextView setzen
        break;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?   What are you seeing that is different from what you expect to see?

Comment: The text doesnt get appended, it doesnt get updated.

Comment: Have you debugged to make sure that `onActivityResult()` is being called and that you **are** getting the title back?

Comment: Thanks codeMagic, i found the mistake (you can see it below as an answer). you made me realize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
i've found the solution, it was a really, really silly mistake of mine, that you couldnt know, because i didnt show that code to you.
In the onClick Method, in which i start the intent of showing the ringtone picker i accidentally called startActivity(intent) instead of startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) so onActivityResult couldn't get called.
Thanks to @codeMagic, who made me realize this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `post(Runnable)` method of the `View` class :

```
textViewRingtone.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textViewRingtone.append(": " + ringtoneTitle);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting textview inside a handler:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK: 
        String ringtoneTitle = null;
        ringtoneUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if(ringtoneUri != null) {
            ringtoneValue = ringtoneUri.toString(); //diesen Wert später in Datenbank abspeichern !!
            ringtoneTitle = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri).getTitle(this); //Titel getten
        }

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                textViewRingtone.append(": " + ringtoneTitle); //Titel zu TextView setzen
            }
        });

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this fixes the problem?

Comment: This won't work, because in Java i can't access the ringtoneTitle variable inside an inner class, that is defined in a different method.

Comment: I had same problem some time back, was trying to animate some view onActivityResult later on i checked googleIO code for this solution. Apparently I guess onActivityResult is called before onResume making views to not function properly (similar to this scenario).

Comment: @YannikKlubertanz , can u try making ringtoneTitle as member variable ? please let me know if this works.